# XLForm Objective-C | Unknown property attribute 'nullable'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, cocoapods, xlform

I installed **cocoapods** to my existing xcode application and added **XLForm** into it. I'm using **Xcode version 6.2** and i'm developing the application using **objective-c**. And then when I try to run the project after installing the dependencies, it gives the following errors in the **"XLFormSectionDescriptor.h"** file.

How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to the latest version of Xcode, which is 7.1.1 as of the time of this post.  If you have some reason that you cannot do this (such as not ready to compile against iOS 9 SDK), you have to get rid of the `nonnull` attribute in that code.  Probably the simplest is to define it away.

```
#define nonnull
```

You probably should surround that with an #ifdef that checks compiler version.  Someone more conversant than I am with the preprocessor will have to supply that bit of code.

The errors are caused by introducing an attribute that the older version of clang included with Xcode 6.x does not understand.

Comment: But I can still compile for iOS 8.2 SDK in Xcode 7.1.1 right?

Comment: You won't have the SDK unless you take steps to migrate from your current install.  You can google for ways to do that.  What you *can* do is set your Deployment Target to 8.2 (or earlier).  Be aware that iOS 9 SDK is buggy, especially when running on older iOS versions.  You should be prepared to test thoroughly or to take steps to compile against iOS 8 SDK.